# Using Django Cache with Celery + Redis Causes Celery to Crash

Tags: django, python-2.7, redis, django-celery, django-cache

I have a Python app running on Heroku and I have Redis and Celery working but when I try to configure Django Cache (which makes my app run much faster), it causes Celery to constantly crash. Here is what I see in my logs after enabling Django Cache:

```
    » 20 Jan 2016 14:13:15.731 2016-01-20 20:13:15.420592+00:00 app web.1 - - serving on http://0.0.0.0:14933
» 20 Jan 2016 14:13:16.110 2016-01-20 20:13:15.837717+00:00 heroku web.1 - - State changed from starting to up
» 20 Jan 2016 14:13:17.109 2016-01-20 20:13:16.760569+00:00 app web.2 - - serving on http://0.0.0.0:28653
» 20 Jan 2016 14:13:17.963 2016-01-20 20:13:17.730287+00:00 app worker.1 - - Traceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 10, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute() File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv) File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/management/commands/celery.py", line 22, in run_from_argv self.validate() File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app) File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items(): File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors self._populate() File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate self.load_app(app_name, True) File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 94, in load_app app_module = import_module(app_name) File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module __import__(name) File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis_cache/__init__.py", line 1, in <module> from redis_cache.backends.single import RedisCache File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis_cache/backends/single.py", line 9, in <module> from redis_cache.backends.base import BaseRedisCache File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis_cache/backends/base.py", line 1, in <module> from django.core.cache.backends.base import BaseCache, InvalidCacheBackendError File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 143, in <module> cache = get_cache(DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS) File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 134, in get_cache "Could not find backend '%s': %s" % (backend, e)) django.core.cache.backends.base.InvalidCacheBackendError: Could not find backend 'redis_cache.RedisCache': 'module' object has no attribute 'RedisCache' Exception
» 20 Jan 2016 14:13:18.172 2016-01-20 20:13:18.098700+00:00 heroku web.2 - - State changed from starting to up
» 20 Jan 2016 14:13:18.781 2016-01-20 20:13:18.537188+00:00 heroku worker.1 - - State changed from up to crashed
```

In my requirements.txt I added:

celery
django-celery
django-redis-cache
redis
hiredis==0.2.0

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Also, in my traceback I see this error:

```
InvalidCacheBackendError File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 143, in <module> cache = get_cache(DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS) File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 134, in get_cache "Could not find backend '%s': %s" % (backend, e)) django.core.cache.backends.base.InvalidCacheBackendError: Could not find backend 'redis_cache.RedisCache': 'module' object has no attribute 'RedisCache' Exception
```